# Is having both http 200 and http 301 codes wrong or completely fine?

Tags: http

So I was stressed by siteliner saying

"www vs. non-www: Different codes were found.
Siteliner accessed your site using both http://www.royz-furniture.com/ and http://royz-furniture.com . Siteliner received the same content, but different HTTP codes: 200 and 301 respectively.

It is recommended that users be able to reach your site using both www and non-www URLs, and see the same content and HTTP codes in both cases."

It says it accessed both sites and also it says that I need to fix it because it is better if it can access both sites.. which it did?... Anyone has any idea if this SITELINER is simply bollocks? Or something I do not completely comprehend?

Comment: I would find it annoying if 'www.x' was not an alias for 'x' for a *public website*. Many sites will simple force the matter, eg. `https://google.com` -> `https://www.google.com`.

Comment: I don't know Siteliner, but for me it sounds like it has it wrong. When it comes to SEO - it's preferable to have only one entry and have either www version 301 redirect to non-www version or the other way around.

Comment: I have no www redirected to www thats why im confused of what its trying to say, though I might have indexed both in search console.

Comment: @user2864740 yes, thats what I do, I find it annoying :D but it does force a redirect, so does that mean siteliner is bugged?